# 1 | 18.07 | 0mysql query sorting with different priority

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

i´ve been hitting rock bottom recently.

What i´m currently trying to do is "sorting" a selection of database entries by date and if the date has passed and value X has not changed then append it ontop of the list and if the value has changed at bottom.

Maybe its a bit better to make some sort of graphic explaining my problem.

```
Entry | "date" | X
1      | 10.07  | 0
1      | 11.07  | 1
1      | 12.07  | 1
1      | 13.07  | 1
1      | 14.07  | 1
1      | 15.07  | 1
1      | 16.07  | 1
1      | 17.07  | 1
1      | 18.07  | 0
1      | 19.07  | 1
```

This should transform to

```
Entry | "date" | X
1      | 19.07  | 1
1      | 17.07  | 1
1      | 16.07  | 1
1      | 15.07  | 1
1      | 14.07  | 1
1      | 13.07  | 1
1      | 12.07  | 1
1      | 11.07  | 1
1      | 18.07  | 0
1      | 10.07  | 0
```

Is that even possible to do with "pure" mysql ?
I´ve been trying to get it sort of working by "sorting" by date, but thats not what i wanted to accomplish in the end.

```
SELECT * FROM table_entries ORDER BY start_date ASC LIMIT 25
```

Have a great day

Comment: `ORDER BY X DESC, start_date DESC`

Comment: `start_date ASC, X DESC`  OR may be only `start_date DESC` enough for you

Comment: What kind of weird date is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got it right you'd like to sort your rows by X value (having ones on top) and then sort them by date. 
You can achieve it by using 
 `ORDER BY X,start_date`
in your query.
 You can specify `ASC` or `DESC` after `X` and `start_date` to obtain the desired effect

Your query wuld become something like this:
`SELECT * FROM table_entries ORDER BY X DESC, start_date ASC LIMIT 25`

Comment: why you people hate commenting so much

Comment: the answer is not a comment, comments are intended to ask questions to clarify the question or the answers

Comment: thank you very much, that helped me a lot. but now i need a way to have items that are "expired" ( date has passed and value not changed so X = 0 ) appended to top, and non "expired" items below em, maybe a image explains it better [link](http://i.imgur.com/VxUCby4.png)

Comment: nvm got it, now i´ve got the issue that the values which are X = 1 ( in the image ) are not sorted by date, so it happens that for example something 1 hour ago is below something 3 hours ago. [image](http://i.imgur.com/MgIdr8L.png)

Comment: stupid question: are you using DATE type in sql right? Not string

Comment: I´m using DATETIME in SQL

Answer (score 0):

Make order by both 'x' and 'date' field. So all the records will be sorted by 'x' first and then by date.

```
SELECT * FROM table_entries ORDER BY x DESC, start_date DESC LIMIT 25
```

Comment: why you people hate commenting so much.